# While loop hanging in parallel

Tags: bash, shell, gnu-parallel

Trying to wrap my head around why this isn't working and how I would fix it. A simple example of a while loop using parallel.

```
set -eu

TOKEN='hello'

query() {
    while [ -z "$TOKEN" ];
    do
        echo "This is $1 and this is $2"
    done
}

export -f query

parallel query ::: 4 4 4 4 ::: 0 1 2 3
```

Whenever I run this from the CLI it just hangs indefinitely, what am I missing here?

Comment: Missing double quotes `"::: 4 4 4 4" "::: 0 1 2 3"` ? Besides, `-z $TOKEN` will never be true since you already initialize it.

Comment: thanks it wasn't the quotes it was because I initialized it, wow what a bonehead mistake, thanks man!

Comment: Welcome. Added an answer if you want to accept it.

Comment: If `[ -z "$TOKEN" ]` was never true, the script would exit immediately. Instead, it's hanging because `[ -z "$TOKEN" ]` is *always* true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[ -z "$TOKEN" ]` will always be true because you didn't export the variable. The loop therefore goes on forever, causing the hang.

Since `parallel` is an external command, all variables you want it and its children to have access to must be exported.

If you export it, the script will terminate successfully (but obviously without output, since the `while` loop will never be entered).

---

Note: environment variables are per process. Updates in one process will not be seen by others, so you can't use them as semaphores or IPC. If this is what you're trying to do, you'll have to use something else (like files or pipes).

Answer (score 1):

@that other guy's answer is correct, but maybe I can tempt you to try `env_parallel`, which automatically exports your environment.

Answer (score 0):

`-z $TOKEN` will never be true since you already initialize it.